# While Commiting a File in Eclipse through SVN, getting error

Tags: svn

[image]

While commiting a file, got this error. Why this error occurs and how to solve this ?

Comment: Can you verify whether the user is having enough permission to access/write the files ?

Comment: yeah user has permissions. While commiting other files i didnot face any problem. While commiting register.html file, i am facing this problem.

Comment: you can try to revert the register.html file and then update it and retry to commit it. Take backup of register.html file before reverting  it.

Comment: @Nikhil it worked. Thanks a lot. Can you explain me why this happens, what causes this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to revert the register.html file and then update it and retry to commit it. Take backup of register.html file before reverting it.

The reason could be missing svn information for that particular file. SVN stores some required info on each file into hidden .svn file for each item in repository. So when svn couldn't fetch this required meta info, it returns errors. In your case FILE NOT FOUND error.

When you have revert it, it restores all the required information.